# How to calculate the height of a WKWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I want to calculate the height of a WKWebView in my project like this, but it always no use, how can I get it?

```
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation     *)navigation{
    [webView sizeToFit];
    _height = webView.frame.size.height ;
}
```

Comment: this method is calling or not?

Comment: Yes, it return a height but not exact.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the scroll view KVO and I've tried evaluating javascript on the document, using things like `clientHeight`, `offsetHeight`, etc...

What worked for me eventually is: `document.body.scrollHeight`. Or use the `scrollHeight` of your top most element, e.g. a container `div`.

I listen to the `loading` WKWebview property changes using KVO and when it's done loading I determine the height like so:

```
[self.webview evaluateJavaScript: @"document.body.scrollHeight"
                       completionHandler: ^(id response, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Document height: %@", response);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Key value Observing

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
...
[self.webView.scrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}


- (void)dealloc
{
[self.webView.scrollView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" context:nil];
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context
{
if (object == self.webView.scrollView && [keyPath isEqual:@"contentSize"]) {
    // we are here because the contentSize of the WebView's scrollview changed.

    UIScrollView *scrollView = self.webView.scrollView;
    NSLog(@"New contentSize: %f x %f", scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height);
}
}
```

This would save the use of JavaScript and keep you in the loop on all changes.

Comment: I am so sorry for reply you so late,I solved this problem with the help of my friend.Thank you very much.

Comment: If you solved it, could you post the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The bounds of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to its own coordinate system (0,0). The frame of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to the superview it is contained within.

Hence, I think you simply need to target the bounds.height instead of its frame.

Comment: I am so sorry for reply you so late,I solved this problem with the help of my friend.Thank you very much.